# How to zoom LinearLayout in android studio

Tags: android-linearlayout, pinchzoom

I am a beginner in android studio. I want to zoom LinearLayout which contain other views. Is it possible? and how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've found this video it helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRqysuYnDlU&t=434s